# How do I turn hyperlinks on or off in Numbers?

Tags: high-sierra, numbers

How do I turn hyperlinks on or off in Numbers5.2?

Sometimes when I paste email or links into numbers they appear as hyperlinks other times not.

I cannot seem to find any way of changing these (although Write as controls for this).

It is extremely annoying when I try to copy an email address to have a new email created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that up in Numbers Preferences

[image].

Comment: There seem to be 2 “Automatically detect links” checkboxes - I have unticked the  “Automatically apply Links  style” I wonder what the other does?

Comment: OK, the first one is to automatically Detect links in text format, the second one is to automatically convert email and web URL's

Comment: I unchecked both of these boxes but it is still automatically creating links when I open a CSV that includes URLs, and there doesn't seem to be a way to bulk remove them. Numbers seems extremely sensitive to hyperlinks (eg clicking an un-selected cell with a hyperlink in it triggers the hyperlink) and it is very annoying. I have never wanted to visit a URL by clicking it in a spreadsheet. Anybody else find this setting is broken? Numbers 6.1 on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6.